# how to use the factanal and sjt.pca command in R?

Tags: r, statistics, pca, sjplot

Thanks to everyone for reading my question. i am trying to understand the principal component analysis using R.

I use this example, the same which appear in factanal() documentation

First, i create my variables:

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6)
v2 <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,3,3,4,6,5)
v3 <- c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,4,6)
v4 <- c(3,3,4,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,5,6,4)
v5 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,6,4,5)
v6 <- c(1,1,1,2,1,3,3,3,4,3,1,1,1,2,1,6,5,4)
```

Then i use a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)
```

I use the factanal commmand

```
factanal(df,3)
```

I often use this command, always give result according to the book i use. But i was trying to use the sjt.pca command inside the sjPlot library, because of cronbach's alpha automatic calculation and the html output:

```
library(sjPlot) 
sjt.pca(df)
```

This is where i am not understanding the sing (+ or -), for example:
The sing "-" in component 3, variables v3 and v4 using `sjt.pca()`. This is not present in `factanal()` where all loadings are positives and is not present in:

```
library(psych)
psych::pca(r = df,nfactors = 3)
```

Using this library, all loading are positives.

And a second question is: Why they have different order? factor 1 in `factanal()` is componet 2 in `sjt.pca()`.

As far i know both are using varimax rotation by default. Maybe these are basic questions, i am not an expert. Please help.

Comment: I guess it's because `factanal()` computes a factor analysis, while `sjt.pca()` computes a principal component analysis (see [this link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-are-the-differences-between-factor-analysis-and-principal-component-analysi) for details on the difference). However, in the [current dev-version of sjPlot](https://github.com/strengejacke), a method `sjt.fa()` to compute a factor analysis.

Comment: Ok, that help a bit, but the sign (+ or -) is different even compared to `library(psych)`      
`psych::pca(r = df,nfactors = 3)`